# adding sums of rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i need to add up the elements of each row and print them out and do the same with columns

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5                                                                                                                                                               
 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10                                                                                                                                                              
 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15
```

this is the output of my multi-array. So, I would have to add up 1,6, and 11 and do the same with every column. Then, do the same with rows, adding 1,2,3,4,5. etc

Comment: You're decomposing the problem statement correctly.  So, convert your understanding into code.

Comment: well, I know that you have to use a for loop to go through the rows and columns but I don't know how to.

Comment: How would you add the columns and rows manually?  Pay attention to the array subscripts as you manually add the columns and rows.  That will be your for loops answer.

Comment: so would the for loop be in row-major order or column-major order or two different for loops for rows and columns?

Comment: Two different for loops, since the number of columns does not equal the number of rows.

Comment: ok ill see what i can do.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate all row in array . now you have 3 arrays then do for loop and sum array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i] and put the results in array4 .

if you print array4 ,you have summation of every column.